# params best practice ? if params[:body] is empty, read some file instead

Tags: ruby-on-rails

if params[:body] is empty, read some file instead.

is there a better way?

```
default_source_file = '/tmp/file'                                                                                                                                                                             
body = if params[:body].blank?
  IO.read(default_source_file) 
else
  params[:body]
end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would use `present?` method to check the presence as I find the code reads better..

```
body = params[:body].present? ? params[:body] : IO.read(default_source_file)
```

Answer (score 0):

That's usually how I go about doing something like this. You can also wrap that logic in a private method to clean up the code some.

Answer (score 0):

```
body = params[:body].blank? ? IO.read 'tmp/file' : params[:body]
```